# Creating key value pairs from json on import

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, geojson

I am new to jquery - I have a valid geojson file whose `features` I would like to access and convert into an object of key-value pairs.  My objective is to only use `properties.cat` as the key and `properties.name` as the value (all other data can be ignored).  Here is a sample:

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::3857" } },
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "cat": "A", "name": "Aberdeen"}, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 16.37208, 48.20849 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "cat": "B", "name": "Berlin"}, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 4.3517103, 50.8503396 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "cat": "C", "name": "Copenhagen"}, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 4.3517103, 50.8503396 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "cat": "D", "name": "Dublin" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 12.56553, 55.67594 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "cat": "E", "name": "Edinburgh"}, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -3.7037902, 40.4167754 ] } }
]
}


  $.getJSON("sample.geojson", function(json) {

    console.log(json.features[0].properties.cat);

      });
```

As was pointed out below, `features` is an array. 
How could one create an object of key value pairs directly from every feature property in the json so as to have the following output:

```
{A : Aberdeen, B: Berlin, C: Copenhagen, D: Dublin, E: Edinburgh}
```

Comment: Did you try logging the json variable to the console prior to parsing it?

Comment: what is var obj is ment for??

Comment: I've edited the question. Please reopen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The callback function for `$.getJson` method has response already parsed automatically.

Also, **features** object is an array. Use this:

```
console.log(json.features[0].properties.cat);
```

For making key-value pairs you can use `reduce` method, which accepts a `callback` provided method applied for every item.

```js
var json= {
      "type": "FeatureCollection",
      "crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::3857" } },
      "features": [
      { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "cat": "A", "name": "Aberdeen"}, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 16.37208, 48.20849 ] } },
      { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "cat": "B", "name": "Berlin"}, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 4.3517103, 50.8503396 ] } },
      { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "cat": "C", "name": "Copenhagen"}, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 4.3517103, 50.8503396 ] } },
      { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "cat": "D", "name": "Dublin" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 12.56553, 55.67594 ] } },
      { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "cat": "E", "name": "Edinburgh"}, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -3.7037902, 40.4167754 ] } }
      ]
}
var obj=json.features.reduce(function(obj,item){
  obj[item.properties.cat]=item.properties.name;
  return obj;
},{});
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: Thanks, I've edited my question

Comment: @the_darkside, have a look to updated answer.

Comment: thanks @Alexandru but when I wrap that in getJSON it does not work:             `$.getJSON("sample.geojson", function(json) {            
            var obj={};
                json.features.reduce(function(obj,item){
                obj[item.properties.cat]=item.properties.name;
                return obj;
              },{});
        console.log(obj)

              });`

Comment: why does this work within the getJSON function?

Comment: It's because console.log is execute before the callback reduce is finished

Comment: Have a look to my answer.

Comment: Your answer works, but it does not take into account that I have to read in the json from a file first.  I need to use `getJSON` because My actual json file is much larger and I cannot include it in the script.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Do you use node.js like server-side ?

Comment: Like you posted the question , I suppose that the part which read from file is working good.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145822/discussion-between-the-darkside-and-alexandru-ionut-mihai).